# Can I make a function to accept N ints where N is a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, syntactic-sugar

I have a situation where I need to pass in a variable number of integers (known at compile time).

I need to achieve something like this:

```
template <unsigned N>
void myFunc(std::array<int, N> values)
{
    // Do something useful with the values
}
```

I hoped the above would work and could be called like this, conveniently without creating a temporary object;

`myFunc<4>({1, 2, 3, 4});`

This did in fact work, but the problem is that this also works...

`myFunc<4>({1, 2});`

which of course leaves two of the values uninitialised, unbeknownst to me and the user.

I believe this would work:

```
template <unsigned N>
void myFunc(std::vector<int> values)
{
    assert(values.size() == N);
    // Do something useful with the values
}
```

```
myFunc<4>({1, 2}); // Goes bang
myFunc<4>({1, 2, 3, 4}); // OK
```

Unfortunately I can't allocate memory in my environment), so I have to do everything on the stack (and can't just accept a vector of which I could check the size).

I see myself as having two options.

1. Use an object which is compile-time sized and based off of the length of the initialiser list
2. Use some magic recursive C++ parameter pack syntax to allow a variable number of ints, but that's beyond me.

Comment: There's [`std::array::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size) you don't need `N` at all.

Comment: Do you want that the user has to explicitly specify the number of elements in the call or are you fine with `N` being deduced to the correct number?

Comment: Also, the other elements are not left uninitialized. They are value-initialized.

Comment: It sounds like you rather need/want a variable sized container, which is taken as template parameter for your function. Something like `template <typename T>
void myFunc(T& c) { // Do something useful with the values accessing c.size()
}`

Comment: Another valid approach (without std::array) is `template<std::size_t N> void myFunc(int (&values)[N])`, but the version with std::array should be fine.

Comment: @user17732522 This is ultimately a constructor for a class where N already set; I want to assert that all values are passed in initialised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::array<int, 4> arr{ 0, 1};` is fine; the elements that aren't specified are simply zero-initialized. If you don't want this to work, `std::array` isn't the right class to use for you (or to be more precise: you cannot have it impose the desired restrictions).

You could of course create a variadic template and restrict the parameters according to your requirements:

```
template<size_t N, std::convertible_to<int>...Args>
requires (sizeof...(Args) == N)
void f(Args&&...args)
{
    std::array<int, N> values{args...};
    for (auto e : values)
    {
        std::cout << e << '\n';
    }
}

...

f<4>(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Why specify the number of elements multiple times though? Just use C++17's functionality doing CTAD and deduce the template parameter of the function based on the argument type:

```
template<size_t N>
void f2(std::array<int, N> const& values)
{
    for (auto e : values)
    {
        std::cout << e << '\n';
    }
}

...

f2(std::array{ 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

or avoid the necessity of using a template by simply using an `std::initializer_list<int>` as function parameter:

```
void f3(std::initializer_list<int> values)
{
    for (auto e : values)
    {
        std::cout << e << '\n';
    }
}

...

f3({ 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

Comment: These are all excellent solutions, thank you! I didn't realise that std::initializer_list could be specialised to only accept one type; this looks to be the cleanest solution and probably what I will use. I'm not sure I have the right C++17 support for CTAD, but I can see how it could work if I did.

I assume that the first solution could be rewritten to use `std::enable_if` instead of `requires` for the same reason?

Comment: Are uninitialised std::array elements definitely zero-initialised if a "partial" initialisation is provided?